# Finding prime project euler

Tags: python, project

Find the 10,001st prime number.

I am trying to do Project Euler problems without using copying and pasting code I don't understand.
I wrote code that finds whether a number is prime or not and am trying to modify it to run through the first 10,001 primes. I thought that this would run through numbers until my break, but it's not working as intended. Bear in mind I have tried a few other ways to code this and this was the one I thought could work. I am guessing that I somewhat made a mess of what I had before.

```py
import math
import itertools
counter = 0
counters = 0
for i in itertools.count():
    for n in range (2, math.ceil(i/2)+1):
        if i%n == 0:
            counter+=1
    if counter == 0 or i == 2:
        counters+=1
    if counters == 10001:
        break
    else:
        pass
print(i)
```

Comment: If `i%n==0` then the number *isnt* prime

Comment: Isn't my code checking that if i%n == 0 for atleast 1 n then counter is atleast 1 and so counter is not == 0? And this would mean that I am counting it as a prime by counters+=1.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that, counter and counters were such similar names I didn't see the difference, it might be worth giving them better names such as `prime_count` and `factor_count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close to the right solution. Remember next time to tell us what exactly you expected and what you got instead. Don't write something like

> but it's not working as intended

Here are some changes you have to make to make it work and to make it faster !

```
import math
import itertools
counter = 0
counters = 0
nth_prime = 0
for i in itertools.count():
    # ignore numbers smaller than 2 because they are not prime
    if i < 2:
        continue
    # The most important change: if you don't reset your counter to zero, all but the first prime number will be counted as not prime because your counter is always greater than zero
    counter = 0
    for n in range (2, math.ceil(i/2)+1):
        if i%n == 0:
            counter = 1
            # if you find out your number is not prime, break the loop to save calculation time
            break;

    # you don't need to check the two here because 2%2 = 0, thus counter = 1    
    if counter == 0:
        counters+=1
    else:
        pass
    if counters == 10001:
        nth_prime = i
        break
print(nth_prime)
```

That code took me 36.1 seconds to find 104743 as the 10.001th prime number.

Comment: This looks very helpful thank you (and very similar to what I had!). However what am I missing as this is not printing i for me.

Comment: actually for me it does. Maybe its because i do that in a ipython-notebook. Just use another variable to store the nth prime number, i made an edit.