# Error fixed,efficiency feedback Project Euler 12

Tags: python

This code is supposed to find the value of the first triangular number with 500 divisors. Problem 12 of ProjectEuler. I have used the help of others to fix an integer division by zero error on p. At this point I am wondering if anyone has a tip on how to simplify the problem. (Finding the first triangular number with 100 divisors takes ~1 minute, and the one with 500 never finished). At the moment I am trying to find a mathematical property that I might be able to take advantage of as doing things like attempting to skip prime numbers seems like it will take nearly just as long.

```py
import itertools
count = 0
j = 0
for i in itertools.count():
    count = 0
    if i > 0:
        j = i*(i+1)/2
    for p in range (1, int(j**0.5)+1):
        if j%p == 0:
            count+=1
    if count > 250:
        break
print (int(j))
```

Comment: Try `for p in range (1, int(j**0.5)+1)`. The error comes from `j%p` when p is 0

Comment: Oh, the if statement afterwards doesn't take care of that?

Comment: @DerekLuna no: `j % p` is an error it `p` is zero and this needs to be evaluated before the `if` statement.

Comment: No, it doesn’t take care of it because you are checking both the conditions. So indeed you are evaluating the division

Comment: I appreciate the help, however this seems that I need to do a bit more work or something is wrong. After noticing long numbers taking forever, I checked a few smaller count values and for count == 4 I don't even the answer 6 to come up (still running). Must be something wrong, if someone has a suggestion I will look at it if I give up.

Comment: What guidelines am I not following that warrant downvotes on every post I make? It is pretty clear I am also looking for feedback on my code (as it is not working) and provided enough information. If it is too easy for you just ignore it. Mathstackexchange seems way friendlier to non-professionals. It's like you have to write as essay to ask a question on here just because some people want to cheat.

Comment: Just a tip: the ```count = 0``` may need to be inside the big loop.

Comment: Thank you. I have added that before but didn't edit the post. The code works at this point but is very slow. For count == 100 It took about ~1 minute.

Comment: "What guidelines am I not following that warrant downvotes on every post I make?"—In this particular case, it's posting an off-topic question. Your code works, and you're asking for general feedback. SO is for _specific_, concrete problems. Questions that are primarily opinion-based are off-topic. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. You can also read tips about asking questions in [ask].

Comment: feedback to get a faster program is not opinion-based and is a concrete problem so you can remove your downvote now that you understand

Comment: @Chris, note that this question originally was about a ZeroDivisionError and is now a completely different question. Derek, now *that's* against the guidelines. Also, asking follow-up questions in comments is not allowed. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a help forum. Please read the [tour], [ask] , [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask], especially if all your posts seem to get downvoted.

Comment: NB: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422865/finding-prime-project-euler

Comment: @DerekLuna, it doesn't look like a concrete problem to me: "At this point I am wondering if anyone has a tip on how to simplify the problem." It might be possible to ask this question in a way that's on-topic, but this isn't it. Again, _please_ read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every divisor of `j` less than its square root, there is exactly one divisor over its square root.  This fact is very useful and makes it possible to count the divisors of `j` while only iterating up to its square root.  This drastically reduces the amount of work needed.

Also, `if count == 500:` should be `if count > 500:`

I would post my code, but Project Euler discourages posting complete solutions to their problems.

Comment: for p in range (1, int(j**0.5)+1):
        if j%p == 0:
            count+=2

Comment: count == 100 was very fast for this, and it seems right. count == 500 been at ~2 minutes already so far.

Comment: I checked a couple large values and it seems wrong, attempting to fix it.

Comment: @DerekLuna You need to be checking count > 500, not count == 500

Comment: I need to find the first such triangular number with 500 divisors.

Comment: The code I have works for certain numbers, but not others, such as 250 the one I need. I am not sure if it has to do with my for p in range (1, ...) line where the number of divisors might get messed up due to the rounding?

Comment: @DerekLuna The problem is "What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?" (from Project Euler's web site).  This requires count > 500.

Comment: I appreciate this very much your help made this work much faster.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get a 23 to 25% speed-up if you use xrange instead of range**
I learned this concept from codereview

for example:

```
divisors(n,start):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    for i in xrange(st, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            cnt=1
            while(n%i==0):
                n/=i
                cnt+=1
            return divisors(n,i+1)*cnt
    return 2
```

we find p, the first prime factor of n. If p^k is the maximum power of p that divides n, (k+1)*divisors(n/p^k) is the number of divisors of n. start is just a starting point for checking prime divisors.

```
for n in xrange(1,1000000):
    Tn=(n*(n+1))/2
    if n%2==0:
        cnt=divisors(n/2)*divisors(n+1)
    else:
        cnt=divisors(n)*divisors((n+1)/2)
    if cnt >= 500:
        print Tn
        break
```

Comment: This assumes the OP is using Py2.X. This is no longer true for Py3. I would suggest moving to Py3 if you can as Py2.X will soon be EOL.

Comment: @AChampion thank you for the information, I will create this one for Python 3 too.